# Is it possible to re-do function, so it can be used many times with a different values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which I will be using many times, just with a different values.

```js
$('.switch').click(function() {
        var frontImg = $('#frontImg');
        var frontImg1 = FrontImagePath + darkImageID + ".png";
        var frontImg2 = FrontImagePath + frontImageID + ".png";
        frontImg.attr('src', frontImg.attr('src') == frontImg1 ? frontImg2 : frontImg1);

        var sideImg = $('#sideImg');
        var sideImg1 = FrontImagePath + darkSideID + ".png";
        var sideImg2 = FrontImagePath + sideImageID + ".png";
        sideImg.attr('src', sideImg.attr('src') == sideImg1 ? sideImg2 : sideImg1);
    });
```

Is it possible to re-do it/make it shorter, so I can use it for a different .click() event, by just changing var values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addClick(e) {
        e.click(function() {
                var frontImg = $('#frontImg');
                var frontImg1 = FrontImagePath + darkImageID + ".png";
                var frontImg2 = FrontImagePath + frontImageID + ".png";
                frontImg.attr('src', frontImg.attr('src') == frontImg1 ? frontImg2 : frontImg1);

                var sideImg = $('#sideImg');
                var sideImg1 = FrontImagePath + darkSideID + ".png";
                var sideImg2 = FrontImagePath + sideImageID + ".png";
                sideImg.attr('src', sideImg.attr('src') == sideImg1 ? sideImg2 : sideImg1);
        });
}
```

Comment: So if I need to use it again, how can I call that without doing copy > paste of the full code?

Comment: addClick(post your element in here);